# Tracking conversion rate of users who clicked on facebook posts

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, kpi

I have an application that posts on the users' friends walls. clicking on the wall post will cause the user to navigate to out website.
I want to track how many users signed up for the website having reached it by clicking on a facebook post. Is there a way to do it using google analytics and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post something to the user's wall, add the `ref` parameter in. When someone clicks on the link, the `ref` parameter will get sent back to your site so you know the user came from facebook. Then it's up to you to detect this and log it in Google Analytics.

Comment: shouldn't the referrer be set automatically? Isn't facebook redirecting all traffic through https://www.facebook.com/l.php?

Comment: Yes, the referrer is set automatically, but the `ref` parameter can be used to track custom sources. E.g. `ref=website` to indicate that the post originated from a website. Something shared without ref would indicate an organically shared post.

Comment: whats the difference to utm_source?

Comment: `utm_source` can be used too. Google already tracks Facebook referrals without this. See Acquisition > Social.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Facebook Insights to track stats like this. You can read lots more about it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: This is a great source of data but I was unlucky finding the answer to my question there.